# POST form data logs out to console, but doesn't get sent to the server

Tags: javascript, express, post, knex.js

I'm building out a simple TO-DO app in Express with Knex as my ORM. Everything is working just fine except for the fact that my form data won't POST to the server from my form. As a debugging measure, I made sure to log the req.body to the console. So the information that I type into my form shows up in the console, so that issue at this point is figuring out why it's not posting to the server. I suspect that my issue is coming solely from the knex query, but I just don't know how or why. Here's what I have so far...

The first file is my app.js
The second contains the POST route in question. Thank you for any help!

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var todo = require('./routes/todo');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/todo', todo);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const knex = require('../db/knex');

/* GET http://localhost:3000/todo page. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  knex('todo')
    .select()
    .then(todos => {
      res.render('all', {
        todos: todos
      });
    })
});

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
  res.render('new');
});

function validTodo(todo) {
  return typeof todo.title == 'string' && todo.title.trim() != '' && typeof todo.priority == 'undefined' && !isNaN(Number(todo.priority));
}

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  if(validTodo(req.body)) {
    const todo = {
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      priority: req.body.priority,
      date: new Date()
    };
    // insert todo into database
    knex('todo').insert(todo, 'id')
      .then(ids => {
        const id = ids[0];
        res.redirect(`/todo/${id}`);
      });
  } else {
    // respond with an error
    res.status(500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: 'Invalid todo'
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: How are you posting data to the server? Try to write minimal app first, which is actually able to read data from your POST:ed requests. You seem to be reading the POST data as json. Are you sending post data as json in body and with correct headers set? Or are you just sending normal form encoded POST which which cannot be read the same way.

Comment: I'm not sure if the syntax of `insert` is right or wrong but you can refer here https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/732 and check if that works

Comment: So I figured out what my issue was. For whatever reason, changing the order of my POST route did the trick. I simply placed my POST route over my GET /new route. I'm really not sure how the logic on this works, but I'm glad I got it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what my issue was. For whatever reason, changing the order of my POST route did the trick. I simply placed my POST route over my GET /new route. I'm really not sure how the logic on this works, but I'm glad I got it fixed.